# Member function already defined in .obj (visual studio)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I've never had this problem in code blocks, but in visual studio classes are giving me error LNK2005 ... already defined in xx.obj. I've read many answers, most of which say to use 'extern' which I don't think is usable on member functions

```
Error: 1>Source.obj : error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall Game::Game(void)" (??0Game@@QAE@XZ) already defined in game.obj

Error: fatal error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found
```

How can I fix this without brute forcing/allowing multiple definitions?

```
//game.h

#ifndef GAME_H
#define GAME_H

#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

class Game
{
    public:
        Game();

    private:
        sf::RenderWindow mWindow;
        sf::CircleShape mPlayer;
};

#endif
```

.

```
//game.cpp

#include "..\Headers\game.h"

Game::Game()
    : mWindow(sf::VideoMode(640, 480), "Beginning")
    , mPlayer()
{
    mPlayer.setRadius(40.f);
    mPlayer.setPosition(100.f, 100.f);
    mPlayer.setFillColor(sf::Color::Cyan);
}
```

.

```
//source.cpp

#include "game.cpp"

int main()
{
    Game game;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Replace in your source.cpp

```
#include "game.cpp"
```

by

```
#include "game.h"
```

You should never include a *.cpp.

Comment: Thanks so much, I'm an idiot. Let the negative votes commence